# SL - unknown column - but it exists

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm a beginner in (my)SQL and this is a class I have in school.
I wrote the following code with my classmates:

```
SELECT 
    w.wo_fname, d.dep_name AS "home", a.dep_invite AS "invite" 
FROM 
    workers w, departments d 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         meeting_invited.worker_id, meetings.dep_invite
     FROM 
         meetings 
     INNER JOIN 
         meeting_invited ON meeting_invited.meeting_id = meetings.meeting_id 
     ORDER BY 
         meeting_invited.worker_id) AS a ON a.worker_id = w.boss_id 
WHERE 
    w.dep_num != a.dep_invite;
```

The mentioned tables have the following columns:

```
workers: wo_id, wo_fname, wo_lname, wo_gender, wo_start_job, dep_num, basic_salary, is_active, boss_id

departments: dep_num, dep_name, max_workers

meetings: meeting_id, startdate, enddate, dep+invite, meeting_subject

meeting_invited: meeting_id, worker_id
```

I wrote `a.worker_id = w.boss_id` instead of `w.wo_id` because the table the school has given us has bad data and this is how it should be treated...

it's supposed to pull a workers name and the department from which he as invited and his home department. It ran just fine on my friends' computer, but when I ran it, I get

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'w.boss_id' in 'on clause'

Why?

Comment: @Jens Of course you can, but you can't use columns from tables that are nit part if the `JOIN` in the `ON` clause. Like here, the `workers w` table us nit part of the join, so it can't be used in `ON w....`

Comment: Explicit JOINs are evaluated _before_ comma separated, implicit ones. This means your ON clause has no knowledge of the w columns.

Comment: Implore joins have not been considered good practice for 30+ years and you should never use them. Use explicit, ANSI, join syntax instead

Comment: Yep, if they still teach you to use comma-separated joins, they should better look for another teacher for this subject. And why the `ORDER BY` in the subquery? subquery results are unordered by definition,so the `ORDER BY` is superfluous. Some DBMS would even raise an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix `JOIN` syntax with the comma in `from` in your case.
Use `join` for all tables

```
SELECT w.wo_fname, d.dep_name as "home", a.dep_invite as "invite" 
FROM workers w join departments d on w.dep_num=d.dep_num INNER JOIN 
(SELECT meeting_invited.worker_id, meetings.dep_invite
FROM meetings INNER JOIN meeting_invited ON meeting_invited.meeting_id = meetings.meeting_id ORDER BY meeting_invited.worker_id) as a
ON a.worker_id = w.boss_id WHERE w.dep_num != a.dep_invite;
```

Comment: Well, you can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Of course you can, but you can't use columns from tables that are not part of if the `JOIN` in the `ON` clause

Comment: And your query is missing a `ON` after the first join